# send a post oneway with jquery.post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I have a variable we will call test_string which I am assigning the string "hello" too.

```
var test_string = "hello";
```

And I want it to post to a php page just oneway
I have tried:

```
$.post('php_page.php', test_string);
```

On the php_page.php I use:

```
$new_var = $_POST['test_string'];
echo $new_var;
```

And get no result.  What am I missing in the $.post()?

Comment: Where do you expect it to echo to? The request is done "behind the scenes" so unless you do something with the return data (look at the jQuery ajax documentation) or use a tool like Chrome's developers tool you won't see anything. In addition, `$.post` should not take a simple string as data in your case, the variable name is not sent with the request.

Comment: Your post syntax is wrong. See the correct syntax in documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this  ---

```
$.post('php_page.php', {test_string:test_string});
```

and let me know

**EDIT MY WORKING CODE** ---

```
test.php


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function handle(){
var test_string = "hello";
$.post('myphp.php', {'test_string':test_string},
function (result){
$("span").html(result);
});
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="button" onclick="handle();" value="Click" />
<span></span>

</body>
</html>
```

> myphp.php

```
<?php
$new_var = $_POST['test_string'];
echo $new_var;
```

Comment: Erm. Not sure it'l work. Which part here will handle the data which the php will return?

Answer (score 2):

As swapnesh implies, you're missing that `$.post` expects an object as the second parameter:

```
$.post('php_page.php', { objkey : objval });
```

Then in PHP you retrieve it with this:

```
$val = $_POST['objkey'];
```

Answer (score 1):

In http requests both post and get,the values are sent as a Name/value pair. In your code you are missing two things. the first thing is you are trying to send just the data without assiging it in to a Name/vale pair. And the second thing is you have not writtien the function to catch the server response.

Please try as follows.

```
$.post('php_page.php', test_string: "hello", function(response) {
 alert(response);
});
```